# Capture a single match only - Regex

Tags: c#, regex, string-matching

i want to capture only the first match through the expression

```
<p>.*?</p>
```

i have tried `<p>.*?</p>{1}` but it is not working it returns all the p tags which are in the html document, please help

Comment: Why are you using regex to grab the inner contents of an element? And what language is this? PHP?

Comment: What returns all the matches?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you are using a method which returns every match in the string given a regex, that being the case you need to anchor the regex to the beggining of the string so it doesn't return every match, but only the first one:

```
^.*?<p>.*?</p>
```

Use parentheses to capture what you want to capture.

PS: Here goes the standard 'avoid using regex to parse HTML, use a proper HTML parser' advice. This simple regex **will fail** for nested `<p>` sections (which I don't recall if are valid in HTML, but still you can probably get them even if they aren't).

Comment: Add more context to the question then, what language are you using, what's the code you are trying, what's your input data...

Comment: I can only echo Vinko's warning, but it may be possible to fine-tune the regex. Which language are you using?

Comment: Then you'll need someone with C# knowledge (not me)

Comment: Use what Lukáš Lalinský said, you are probably using Matches() (which returns everything) instead of Match() (which returns first match)

Answer (score 2):

The [`Regex.Match`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcw2f1c.aspx) method does this by default, and the regular expression is correct.

```
Regex regex = new Regex("<p>(.*?)</p>");
Match match = regex.Match("<p>1</p><p>2</p>");
Console.WriteLine("{0}", match.Value);
```

Running this program will print `1`.